# Cambio de método con iron-ajax. Envía OPTIONS en vez de POST

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, polymer

Estoy haciendo una práctica y no consigo avanzar. Estoy enviando una petición POST al servidor y constantemente veo que en vez de mandarla como POST la manda como OPTIONS, desencadenando un error. Además siempre me cambia la URL añadiendo una ? al final de la misma.

Mi código completo es:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html"> <link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">



<dom-module id="user-login">   <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
      .boxed-aqua {
        background-color: darkblue;
        text-align: center;
        color: ghostwhite;
      } /*
        .form {         margin: 0 auto;         width: 210px;   }   .form label{        display: inline-block;      text-align: right;      float: left;    }   .form input{        display: inline-block;      text-align: left;       float: right;   }
*/


    </style>

      <body>
      <div class="boxed-aqua">
        <h1>The future bank</h1>
        <h2>Cambiando lo cotidiano</h2>
      </div>
        <form class="form">
          <div>
          <label>Usuario:  </label>
          <input placeholder="username" type="text" value="{{username::input}}" required>

          </div>
          <br>
          <div>
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input placeholder="password" type="password" value="{{password::input}}" required>
          </div>
          <br>


          <div>
            <button on-click="login">Acceder</button>
            <span hidden$="{{!isLogged}}">Bienvenid@ de nuevo</span>
            <input type="button" value="Registrarse">
          </div>


        </form>
      </body>

      <iron-ajax
          id="doLogin"
          url="http://localhost:8080/v1/login"
          handle-as="json"
          content-type="application/json"
          method="POST"
          on-response="manageAJAXResponse"
          on-error="showError"
        >
      </iron-ajax>



  </template>

  <script>
    /**
     * @customElement
     * @polymer
     */
    class UserLogin extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'user-login'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          username:{
           type: String,
           value:"felipe2"
         },
         password: {
           type: String,
           value: "123456"
         },
         jwt:{
           type: String
         },
         isLogged: {
           type: Boolean,
           value: false
         }
        };
      }

      login(){
       console.log("--login--");
       console.log(this.username);

       var loginData = {
         "username":this.username,
         "password":this.password
       }

       this.$.doLogin.body = JSON.stringify(loginData);
       this.$.doLogin.generateRequest();

       console.log("Petición de login enviada");
     }

     manageAJAXResponse(data){
       console.log("--manageAJAXResponse--");
       console.log(data.detail.response);
       this.isLogged = true;
       this.dispatchEvent(
       new CustomEvent(
         "jwt",
         {
           "detail":{"jwt": data.detail.response.jwt}
         }
       )
     )

     }

     showError(error){
       console.log("--showError--");
       console.log(error);
       console.log(error.detail);
       this.isLogged = false;

     }


    }

    window.customElements.define(UserLogin.is, UserLogin);   </script> </dom-module>
```

Estoy usando Polymer 2 y para lanzar la petición iron-ajax 2.1.3.

Una evidencia de lo que llega al servidor:

172.20.0.1 - - [29/Jun/2019:15:24:21 +0000] "OPTIONS /v1/login HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "http://127.0.0.1:8081/components/the-future-bank/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"

[image: Evidencia ejecución navegador]

Os agradecería cualquier pista.

Comment: Ya encontré el problema, era el propio servidor que no permitía el options. Gracias de todas formas.

Answer (score 0):

El problema estaba en el servidor. No tenía permitido la opción de OPTIONS.

Comment: Y como lo corregiste?, considera que cuando aportas una respuesta esta misma debe dejar en claro el problema y como se reasolvió

Comment: No lo corregí yo, lo modificó el equipo que desarrollaba en el servidor. Básicamente, no había especificado ese método como  permitido por el servidor (POST, GET, ..., OPTIONS), con lo cual, cada vez que llegaba el OPTIONS daba un error. Esto no pasaba desde el Postman ya que el navegador por defecto lanza un options con cada petición.